# Spring Boot JPA @Query Update does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using Springboot and I'm trying to make a function that updates an attribute using native query

this is a part of my interface:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true) // mandatory if native quaries are modying something in the dataBase
@Transactional
@Query("""
    update pojazd 
    set czy_zarchiwizowany = true 
    where id =: selected_id""", nativeQuery = true) 
fun archwizujPojazd(@Param("selected_id") selected_id:Long):Boolean
```

The function works. It returns true, but it has no effect on the dataBase

Any help?

I have browsed through a bunch of similar topics on here with no solution.

I would be very glad for your help.

Comment: It seems like you're not getting an error, but I wouldn't have expected this to work with the extra space in `: selected_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true) 
@Transactional
@Query(value = "update pojazd  set czy_zarchiwizowany = true 
    where id = :selected_id", nativeQuery = true) 
fun archwizujPojazd(@Param(value="selected_id") Long selected_id);
```

Comment: I just had to change that updating function to void.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the class details of "pojazd". There may be a chance of miss matching the name "id". It will be helpful, if you go through this blog [Spring Data JPA @Modifying Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation).